# How to rename a table that has ".csv" in the name

Tags: azure-synapse, sp-rename

I have several tables whose names end with `.csv`. I.e. schema.table1.csv, schema.table2.csv.

How can I remove the `.csv` or rename them without the offending characters?

Per this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488677/how-to-rename-a-table-name-that-has-a-hyphen-in-it-sql-server-2008-r2) I tried this:

```sql
exec sp_rename @objname = 'schema.[table1.csv]', @newname = 'table1';
```

But I'm getting this error when I run it:

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function sp_rename.

Per @AlwaysLearning's question, here's the result of `SELECT @@VERSION`:

> Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.20438.0 Jan 10 2023 20:57:20 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Comment: I can't replicate your problem: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y20MlTDK)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? i.e.: what's the output of `SELECT @@VERSION`? This can be a bit flaky in Azure Synapse Analytics, for example.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-tables-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I updated my question with the version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
RENAME OBJECT schema.[table1.csv] TO [table1];
```

for details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/rename-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest

(Btw: sp_rename is totally something different in Azure Synapse. As of today It only supports renaming of a column only. See details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest)